# How do I print variables from inside a function?

Tags: haskell

So I have a main function (foo) that recursively calls two other functions (step1 & step2). foo will add a1 to a2 a `count` amount of times and then return (a1, a2). How can I print the variables count, a1, and a2 at each step?

```
-- adds a1 to a2 a `count` number of times
-- returns (a1, a2) once count reaches 0
foo :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
foo count a1 a2 | count == 0 = (a1,a2)
                | otherwise = foo count' a1' a2'
                where (count', a1', a2') = let (count'', a1'', a2'') = step1 count a1 a2
                                           in step2 count'' a1'' a2''

-- adds a2 to a1. How to print out count, a1 and a2' here?
step1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
step1 count a1 a2 = (count, a1, a2')
    where
        a2' = a1 + a2

-- decrements count by 1. How to print out count', a1 and a2 here? Or can I do these prints somewhere in the `foo` function? 
step2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
step2 count a1 a2 = (count', a1, a2)
    where
        count' = count - 1
```

This is a simplified version of code from a larger code base. I am open to using a different approach. The example output that I am looking for is:

$> foo 3 4 5

3 4 5

3 4 9

2 4 9

2 4 13

1 4 13

1 4 17

0 4 17

(4, 17)

EDIT: I just realized I could probably store intermediary results in a list and then print from that list. But am I correct to think that I would have to pass the list as an argument to the functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to change `foo` and make it operate in the `IO` monad. Effectively this "tags" the function as being impure (i.e. it has side effect, such as printing on `stdout`) which allows it to call functions such as `print`. Here's an example:

```
foo :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> IO (Integer, Integer)
foo count a1 a2 = do
    print (count, a1, a2)
    case count of
        0 -> do
            print (a1,a2)
            return (a1,a2)
        _ -> do
            let (count'', a1'', a2'') = step1 count a1 a2
                (count', a1', a2') = step2 count'' a1'' a2''
            foo count' a1' a2'
```

**Note**: If you want to print these values for debugging purposes, then you can use `Debug.Trace` as shown in [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756675/6776093). You should do that for debugging purposes only and for no other reason.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This might work for the foo function but I would need to print at each of the step functions (not just at the end like in your example) . So I would have to change the output type of step1 and step2, which would cause some binding issues inside of the foo function. Ideas?


EDIT: Never mind. I see now that your solution works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

For debugging purposes only, you can use `Debug.Trace`. For example:

```
import Debug.Trace

-- adds a2 to a1. How to print out count, a1 and a2' here?
step1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
step1 count a1 a2 = traceShowID (count, a1, a2')
    where
        a2' = a1 + a2

-- decrements count by 1. How to print out count', a1 and a2 here? Or can I do these prints somewhere in the `foo` function? 
step2 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
step2 count a1 a2 = traceShowID (count', a1, a2)
    where
        count' = count - 1
```

`traceShowID :: Show a => a -> a` is basically `id` with the (**unannounced**) side effect of also printing the argument's string representation according to `show`.